# I hava five threads in java server, how should I do to make them run one task concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, executors

I write a web server in java, and need a task class to upload data to anther server, so I do this as below:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5)
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

The `Task` has implement `Runnable`.
The question is,every time only one thread is scheduled to run this `new Task()`, others just idle, if a large number of data coming, my work queue which store data become very large, more worse, I can't get real time data in anther server.
My English is too bad, I am wandering if you have my got my point, I want to find a way to fix this, can you help me ?

Comment: The executor will start using more than one thread if running your task takes more than 100 seconds (time between each call).

Comment: You have 100 seconds of gap between each run so it will take 1 minute and 40 seconds before it runs again.

Comment: I know that, but I want one more thread run my task at the same time, because there is always many data to upload in my work queue, any idea?

Comment: if you have so much data, why the 100s delay?

Comment: so it seems the only way to improve the situatio is lower delay?

Comment: executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
This will run four tasks.

Comment: may be executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  will by ok?

Comment: Try with what I posted it will run Task() five times every 1.4 minute.

Comment: but this code seems not beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

To run 5 tasks at once you need 5 tasks which take long enough that different threads will be used.  If you add one task, it will use one thread. If you add 5 small tasks, they might be all run by the same thread.

Comment: any way to customise running one task with more than one thread?

Comment: @znlyi If there is only one Task, there can be only one Thread executing it. Maybe you want to achieve something different, but you must explain it better. What do you want to achieve by using delays? Do you want to limit how fast new tasks are submitted for execution? Do you want to limit how fast new tasks actually execute? Why do you want to use more than one thread?

Comment: I want to use more than one thread becase maybe my work queue grow rapidly， I need one more thread to execute my task,and `Task` just a simple task to upload data to another web server.I use delays to guarantee a client has finished its http request to my web server, after that, I upload the client data.

Comment: If you actually want to guarantee anything, you should find out exactly when the client-upload finished instead of imposing some arbitrary delay. Build your Tasks so that they only finish when their *work* is really finished. So that there is no delay needed.

Comment: if without delay, it would keep send data, and occupy http resources. But the client data is stored in `HttpSession`, so I don't exact time when the session is cloed, except `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor `, if there is other way to builde my project better? Thank you .

Comment: Actually, your question above does not provide enough context for a suffcient answer. Maybe somebody else who knows more about efficiently using HTTP resources, requests and responses can answer this better. I just wanted to point out that any delay you give in the STPE is either too low or too high and should be replaced by knowing when exactly the Thread or HTTPSession becomes available again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
Task task=new Task();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

in this way you will have Only one task scheduled to run in 5 threads. just make sure you have Task `thread safe` (as you will be running same task within 5 threads).